# JTable Column Title Blurred

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I created inventory application, when display transaction list from database I use JTabel inside JScrollPane. Set JScrollPane horizontalScrollBar Policy to AS_NEED and JTable setAutoResize to false and Column width set using TableColumnModel as I need. When Width set manually table width going out of viewport and HorizotalScrollBar activate. But I run program and Use scrollbar to see column outside viewport, text and header text get blur during scroll.
Follow given code an screen shoot of project

**SetTableModel using DefaultTableModel**

```
DefaultTableModel dm;
dm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }            
        };
        String titleCol[] = new String[]{"ID","Invoice No","Date","Account Name","Total Amount","Taxeble Amount","Tax %","Tax Amount","Discount Amount","Grand Total"};
        dm.setColumnIdentifiers(titleCol);
        table1.setModel(dm);

       table1.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

**Set Width of Column using TableColumnModel**

```
table1.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table1.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().width, 35));

        TableColumnModel columnModel = table1.getColumnModel();

        columnModel.getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setMinWidth(85);
        columnModel.getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(85);
        columnModel.getColumn(2).setMinWidth(100);
        columnModel.getColumn(2).setMaxWidth(100);
        columnModel.getColumn(3).setMinWidth(250);
        columnModel.getColumn(4).setMinWidth(100);
        columnModel.getColumn(4).setMaxWidth(100);
        columnModel.getColumn(5).setMinWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(5).setMaxWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(6).setMinWidth(75);
        columnModel.getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(75);
        columnModel.getColumn(7).setMinWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(8).setMinWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(8).setMaxWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(9).setMinWidth(130);
        columnModel.getColumn(9).setMaxWidth(130);
```

**Screenshot of Before using Horizotal ScrollBar**
[image]

**Screenshot of After using Horizotal ScrollBar**
[image]

So Is there any solution to avoid blur.

Comment: The posted code seems ok. Could you post SSCCE?

Comment: This may be related: [How to change JTable header height? #not using setXXXSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686535/how-to-change-jtable-header-height/11686731#11686731)

Comment: [don't use setXXSize, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in next line:

```
table1.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table1.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().width, 35));
```

Set height of your header with help of `TableCellRenderer`, for example:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer defaultRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
defaultRenderer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,35));
```